what does a prepositional phrase that follows a that clause modify?
Consider the following sentence:

As secretary, you are to set a meeting agenda that includes discussions in concert with the boss.

What word does the prepositional phrase "in concert with the boss" modify, the verb "set" or the noun "discussions"?

Look for entire syntactic constituents, not just single words.

Throw out as secretary, which is unambiguous, but contributes nothing except distraction to the syntactic analysis. The rest is ambiguous. If in concert with the boss modifies set, you could rephrase it as In concert with the boss, you are to set an agenda for a meeting that includes discussions. If it adjectivally modifies discussions, you'd have You are to set the agenda for a meeting that includes discussions in concert with the boss. You decide which interpretation based on what makes sense, not the syntax itself.

...almost certainly the writer would have intended the first of my two above parsings (addressee is told to work with the boss to set up the agenda). But you have to ask yourself what that includes discussions is doing there in the first place. Personally I think the phrasing is hopelessly garbled.

The original example looks clear enough to me. The PP modifies "discussions", as evident from the fact that the NP is mobile, cf. "[Discussions in concert with the boss] are  to be set in a meeting agenda ...".

Does this answer your question? What is the name of the ambiguity in the phrase "I want to visit clubs with attractive women"?

@carolyn. Where did you find your example, or did you write it yourself?

Can you cite a real source for 'As secretary, you are to set a meeting agenda that includes discussions in concert with the boss…'?
Why not look back at BillJ's Comment, above?


As secretary, you are to set a meeting agenda that includes discussions in concert with the boss.

From the strict meaning of "in concert with" found in Collins and Longman, this preposition is seen to link to "discussion" only in a very imperfect manner.

(Collins) in concert phrase [PHRASE after verb]
If a number of people do something in concert, they do it together.
[formal]

He wants to act in concert with other nations.
Synonyms: together, jointly, unanimously, in unison   More Synonyms of in concert



(Longman) in concert (with somebody) a) formal
people who do something in concert do it together after having agreed on it

Britain has to pursue policies in concert with other EU members.
It appeared that both the accused were acting in concert in the attack upon the deceased.


Collins states that this phrase is used after a verb; also, an examination of the usage of "in concert with" in Google Books shows that it is used without exception as a means of verb complemenation, the verb being in an overwhelming number of cases the verb "to act": "in concert with".
The definition in the SOED does seem to confirm this point of view.

(SOED) in concert a) acting jointly and in harmony (with);

If we take this preposition as modifying "discussions", it is not clear who is participating in discussions with the boss, whereas in the setting  of discussions the secretary and the boss are clearly understood to work jointly.

As secretary, you are to set a meeting agenda that includes discussions together/jointly with the boss.

As secretary, you are to set in concert/together/jointly with the boss a meeting agenda that includes discussions. (Changing the order makes for a  sentence easier to read.)



@BillJ What do you think about Collin's "PHRASE after verb", and the Google Book's result? (only verbs,  verified it?).

@BillJ one would rarely describe a discussion as "in concert with" anything.  An action such as "setting a meeting" is much more likely to be the intended target of that modifier.  With more context, though, it's probably clearer one way or the other.

@LPH Firstly, don't use dictionaries for grammar! Yes, verbs can of course take PP modifiers or complements, but that is not the case here. If the PP modified “set”, then “discussions” would have no complement “an agenda that includes discussions” is meaningless). What discussion? The relative clause modifies “agenda”, so we have “an agenda that includes discussions in concert with the boss”. And note that the PP is mobile: we can say ‘[Discussions in concert with the boss] are to be included in a meeting agenda’. Note also that “in concert” means ‘in conjunction’ or ‘together’ here.

However, it would be possible for the intended meaning to be "As secretary, you are to set in concert with the boss a meeting agenda that includes discussions", in which case the PP ”in concert with the boss” is complement of “set”. I have asked the OP to tell us where the sentence came from.

@BillJ Not to use dictionaries for grammar is not good advice; when a dictionary tells you that an adjective is not used before nouns, that is in all cases much more than a recommendation, it is solid  grammar, and the student would do well to heed such grammatical parts in the entry. I will go on listening to the grammatical specifications in dictionaries. That being said, I will agree with you if you tell me that dictionaries are not all perfect, and that there might sometimes be errors in them as concerns grammar and other parts of their treatment.

It's the advice of many -- perhaps most -- grammarians. You would do well to heed it.  Useful little basic snippets like the one about the position of the adjective can be helpful, but others can be wrong or misleading, or years out-of-date. Take for instance, your quote about "in concert" from the Collins dictionary, You took it to mean that the PP "in concert" was always a modifier of a verb. But that's misleading, as I explained to you earlier, since it can also be complement of a noun, as in "discussions in concert ...".
